# type error b is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

context:
im trying to make a game with a bunch of monsters moving towards the hero which he then has to smack by pressing "a". I have all the monsters with the IDs="monsterX", where X is the number of the monster, in the HTML5 code

error: TypeError: b is undefined
it seems to be the for loop in the last function, attack1, that breaks the entire function, as when i have it commented out, i can play the attack animation, although it does trigger the attack animation on any keyboard input, rather than just "a"

code:

```
    var monsterPos = [0];
var monsterList = [0];
var singleMonster = 123;
var frame = 0;
var isAttacking = false;
var l = 1;

$(document).ready(function()
{
setInterval(moveRight3, 100);
document.addEventListener("keydown", attack1);
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(){isAttacking=false;});
$(".monster").each(monsterLister($(this)));
});

function getPosition(element) {
   var xPosition = 0;
   var yPosition = 0;

while(element) {
    xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft +           element.clientLeft);
    yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
    element = element.offsetParent;
}
return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}

function monsterLister(element)
{
singleMonster = getPosition($(this));
monsterPos[monsterPos.length] = singleMonster.x;
monsterList[monsterList.length] = l;
l++;
}


 function moveRight3()
{
  frame = (frame+1)%4;
    if (!isAttacking) {$("#hero").attr("src","move"+(frame+1)+".png");}
$('.monster').each(function(index, img){$(this).css("left",  (parseInt($(this).css("left"))  - 20))});
}

function attack1(event)
{
if ($(this).keyCode == 97){
    isAttacking = true;
for (q=1, len = monsterPos.length; len > q; q++){
if (400 > monstersPos[q] > 560){
$("monsterList["+q+"]").css(opacity, 0);
}
    $("#hero").attr("src","attack.png");
    console.log("attack");
}
}}
```

Comment: Please consider providing a live demo of the code (JSFiddle, Plnkr...)

Comment: where `b` in your code?

Comment: @Sphaso you can put all code to JSFiddle, if you want. What really mught be helpful in question is HTML.

Comment: There is no variable called `b` in the code you pasted; the error must be elsewhere.

Comment: @AndrewMagee or it variable inside some function in this code

Comment: Yeah, but not in the code currently in the question.

Comment: Most likely you're working with a minified jQuery? `b` sounds like that. Consider using a development version and you'll most likely get a more meaningful error message.